# Knowledge for struct.error: bad char in struct format

Tags: python-3.x

I need help with an abbreviating system using `struct.pack`, the code that is making the error is this:

```
import struct

num = 1002
struct.pack("k", num)
```

Any help? (I also rounded it)

Comment: `struct.pack` does not understand the format string `"k"`, as can be gathered from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters). You might want to try one of the integer formats instead!

Comment: Oh okay, I get it now, but I don't understand how you abbreviate numbers like 1000, was pretty sure that struct.pack() was used for that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do - what do you mean by abbreviating a number? Generally, `struct` and friends are used to pack and unpack binary data. That's useful for, say, binary I/O, or interop with C.